# $f:\overline{\mathbb{B^n}}\to\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\forall x\in S^{n-1}$ ($f(x)=0$ or $\angle x0f(x)$ is acute), then $0\in f(\overline{B^n})$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I struggle with following problem. Let $f:\overline{\mathbb{B^n}}\to\mathbb{R^n}$ be continuous map such that $\forall x\in S^{n-1}$, either $f(x)=0$ or $\angle x0f(x)$ is acute. Show that if mentioned conditions are fulfilled, then $0\in f(\overline{B^n})$.

If there is $x\in S^{n-1}$ such that $f(x)=0$ then we're done. So we can assume that $f|_{S^{n-1}}:S^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R^n_*}$.

I know that if $0\notin f({S^{n-1}})$ and $f|_{S^{n-1}}$ is not null homotopic in $\mathbb{R^n_*}$, then $0\in f(\overline{B^n})$.

However, I do not know how to show that this function is not null homotopic. One way is to show that $f|_{S^{n-1}}$ cannot be extended to continuous function on $\overline{B^n}$. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: $f$ is given to you as a continuous function on the closed ball, so trying to show its restriction cannot be extended is not going to work.

Comment: Hint: Construct a homotopy $f_t$ between $f|S^{n-1}$ and the identity map such that $0\notin Im(f_t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, something like $f_t(x)=tx+(1-t)f(x)$?

Comment: Well, try it and see if it works...

Comment: Well, thanks to angular condition $0\notin Im(f_t)$ but I do not know exactly how to use it.

Comment: Oh, unless this just means that $f$ is not null homotopic, because idenity on sphere is not null homotopic.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk: Right. Now, you can write an answer to your own question.